# <option> not selected when using ng-value

Tags: angularjs

I cannot get a `<select>` to show the correct `<option>` when using `ng-value`.

Given:

```
$scope.EDef.One = "1";
$scope.EDef.Six = "6";
$scope.EDef.Ten = "10";

$scope.modelOne = "1";
$scope.modelTwo = "1";
```

And:

```
<p>ModelOne = {{modelOne}}</p>
<select ng-model='modelOne'>
  <option value="1">It is One</option>
  <option value="6">It is six</option>
  <option value="10">It is ten</option>
</select>

<p>ModelTwo = {{modelTwo}}</p>
<select ng-model='modelTwo'>
  <option ng-value="{{EDef.One}}">It is One</option>
  <option ng-value="{{EDef.Six}}">It is six</option>
  <option ng-value="{{EDef.Ten}}">It is ten</option>
</select>
```

The `<select>` for modelOne is correctly selected, but not for modelTwo.  Why not?

Plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/x3GzeSXvmvaMS4dGuArs

Thanks

**EDIT**

Checking further, `ng-value` does work properly when setting radio buttons:

```
<p>ModelOne = {{modelOne}}</p>
<input type="radio" name='m1' ng-model='modelOne' value="1">One
<input type="radio" name='m1' ng-model='modelOne' value="6">Six
<input type="radio" name='m1' ng-model='modelOne' value="3">Ten

<p>ModelTwo = {{modelTwo}}</p>
<input type="radio" name='m2' ng-model='modelTwo' ng-value="{{EDef.One}}">One
<input type="radio" name='m2' ng-model='modelTwo' ng-value="{{EDef.Six}}">Six
<input type="radio" name='m2' ng-model='modelTwo' ng-value="{{EDef.Ten}}">Ten
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/zKGUaMMfzdzNbnXRRoqz?p=preview

Comment: what about something like this?  https://plnkr.co/edit/T0fpL1UrZCelsOePr9wF?p=preview

Comment: yes, we must use ng-options for select. But question is not about getting result. It states why ng-value not working with select where as only "value" worked without any problem.

Comment: actually it is not necessary to use ng-options with select.  But the issue here is the binding of the value (ng-value) to the 'selected' state of the <select>

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-selected="OptOne" to specify the default option.

```
$scope.OptOne = "1";
$scope.OptSix = "6";
$scope.OptTen = "10";

$scope.modelOne = "1";
$scope.modelTwo = "1";
```

and in html

```
<p>ModelTwo = {{modelTwo}}</p>
<select ng-model="modelTwo">
  <option ng-selected="OptOne" ng-value="OptOne">It is One</option>
  <option ng-value="OptSix">It is six</option>
  <option ng-value="OptTen">It is ten</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATED:**

```
<select ng-model="modelTwo">
  <option ng-selected="modelTwo == OptOne" ng-value="OptOne">It is One</option>
  <option ng-selected="modelTwo == OptSix" ng-value="OptSix">It is six</option>
  <option ng-selected="modelTwo == OptTen" ng-value="OptTen">It is ten</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the drop box to be set to a default value, I'd like set to the current value of ng-model.

Comment: What does it mean "current value". Your ng-model value will change based on value selected from dropdown.

Comment: yes, but the model might also be changed externally, eg. by the result of an ajax call or another UI control element.  Even initializing the model in the controller, $scope.modelTwo = "1" is an example of that.

Comment: then you should use expression inside ng-selected like "ng-selected="modelTwo == OptOne""

Comment: that works but it does seem verbose/clunky.  But then why does the first case work without putting ng-selected in every <option>?